# Having issues with Android being able to sent post requests to my server

Tags: java, android, post

So I'm working on a uni project right now and I've created an App which I wish to have communicate with my server using POST requests.

I've got the code to work without issues when running as a standalone Java file but when I put the code in to my app nothing happens, I've been going at this for around 5 hours now using all sorts of different methods from Sockets to now simple POST requests.

I've included the Android version of the code here, it's essentially the same as the standalone version.

```
//Register on the sever
        String url = "myurl";
        String data = "uuid:!:harry6:,:timestamp:!:1337";
        postData(url, data);

    }

    //Method for sending data to the server
    public static void postData(String urlN, String data) {

        try {
            data = splitArgs(data);
            URL url = new URL(urlN);
            URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
            conn.setDoOutput(true);
            OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
            wr.write(data);
            wr.flush();

            BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
            String line;
            while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(line);
            }
            wr.close();
            rd.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
    }

    //Function which will split the arguments for HTML parsing
    public static String splitArgs(String data){

        HashMap<String, String> finalData = new HashMap<String, String>();

        String[] data2 = data.split(":,:");

        for(String d : data2){
            String[] d2 = d.split(":!:");
            finalData.put(d2[0].toString(), d2[1].toString());
        }

        String encodedString = "";
        String charset = "UTF-8";

        for ( String key : finalData.keySet() ) {
            try{
                encodedString += URLEncoder.encode(key, charset) + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(finalData.get(key), charset) + "&";
            }catch(Exception e){

            }
        }

        encodedString = encodedString.substring(0, encodedString.length()-1);

        return encodedString;
    }
```

Any advice would be great, I've also enabled the internet permission in the manifest!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use AsyncTask class to post data to the server. Here's the code:

First add Okhttp library by including the following dependency

```
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.6.0'
```

This Async class will help you to send post request to server.

```
private class GetMyTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {

    private final String mToken;

    GetMyTask(String token) {
        mToken = token;
    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // TODO: attempt authentication against a network service.
        try {
            responsecode = 0;
            responsedata = "";
            responsemsg = "";
            RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(JSON, parameters);
            Request request = new Request.Builder()
                    .url(url)
                    .post(body)
                    .addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + mToken)
                    .addHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
                    .addHeader("Content-Length", String.valueOf(url.length()))
                    .build();
            Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
            responsecode = response.code();
            responsemsg = response.message();
            responsedata = response.body().string();
        }
        catch (IOException iox){
            if(iox!=null){
            }

            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(final Boolean success) {

        try {
            if (success) {
                if (responsecode == 200) {
                    //GSON responsedata
                    if(responsedata!=null) {
                        if (responsedata != "") {
                            JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(responsedata);
                        }
                    }
                } else if(responsecode==401){
//                        Toast.makeText(this, "Somthing went wrong!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                else {
//                        Toast.makeText(this, responsedata, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            } else {
                validationmsg = "Access denied!";
//                    Toast.makeText(this, validationmsg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            if(e!=null){
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCancelled() {
//            showProgress(false);
    }
}
```

And call this class when you want to send post request to server:

```
private GetMyTask myTask = null;
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .connectTimeout(5, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
                .readTimeout(5, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
                .build();

myTask = new GetMyTask(access_token);
url = "";  // your server URL
myTask.execute();
```